# SuperObject cannot handle null string

Tags: delphi, null, delphi-xe2, superobject

Some JSON serializers return `null` for an empty string datafield, e.g.

```
{
 "searchtext": null,
 "moretext": "contains something",
 "bookdate": 1377468000000,
 "empid": 12345,
 "listtype": 1
}
```

I'm using SuperObject to create a ISuperObject:

```
var
  FJSONRequest: ISuperObject; 
then
  FJSONRequest := SO(Request.Content);   // Webservice request
```

This returns an object with a string containing the text `'null'`.

Obviously this is because SuperObject does not care about the quotes (`"searchtext": a` gives the same results as `"searchtext": "a"`).

Before I dive into the 980-line tokenizer routine, does any one have a solution?

I'm thinking along the lines (either/or):

- leave the null datafield out of the JSON object
- return an empty string

If all else fails I could still do

```
FJSONRequest := SO(StringReplace(Request.Content,': null,',':,',[rfReplaceAll]));
```

because I only need to handle requests coming from an app from one of our developers, but that's not foolproof.
(No, he cannot suppress the `null` because [there's a bug in the way Mono handles his datacontract](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7999).)

BTW I'm experiencing exactly [the behaviour mentioned here](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/issues/detail?id=45), but in another part of the SuperObject code, so that workaround does not do the job.

Comment: null is not the same thing as an empty string. It has a completely different meaning. Your `StringReplace` won't work. Think what it does to the text annulled.

Comment: Set my stringReplace() tighter, but indeed not foolproof.

Comment: The bug you mention appears to have been [fixed more than a year before it was reported](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/detail?r=55d5b03a621bc2570e50da5d745ded4e9b0dfa12). And tokenization of `null` seems correct, too, inasmuch as Super Object correctly parses valid JSON and rejects invalid JSON at all. Look for [handling of the `tsNull` state in `TSuperObject.ParseEx`](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/superobject.pas#3400). Are you sure you're using a recent version of the code?

Comment: @Rob: Bummer. The official 1.2.4 ZIP file in the download section https://code.google.com/p/superobject/downloads/list dates from 2010, but the individual files in https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/ have updates up until Oct 2012. Thanks, I'll do file comparisons and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official 1.2.4 ZIP file in the download section http://code.google.com/p/superobject/downloads/list dates from 2010, but the individual files in http://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse have updates up until Oct 2012.

If you go to that last URL and click on `Download zip` you can retrieve them.

These updated files let you use the special case `null`.

The code is still 'forgiving' if you omit the quotes around the string value:

```
{
 "bookdate": 1377554400000,
 "searchtext": a,
 "listtype": 1
}
```

but it now handles the special case

```
{
 "bookdate": 1377554400000,
 "searchtext": null,
 "listtype": 1
}
```

as if it was

```
{
 "bookdate": 1377554400000,
 "searchtext": ,
 "listtype": 1
}
```

or

```
{
 "bookdate": 1377554400000,
 "listtype": 1
}
```

[Do not accidentally type `nil` or `NULL`]

This release supports up until VER230 (Delphi XE2) [Note that the 'official' 1.2.4 did not even compile on more recent Delphi versions], so for later versions of Delphi you'll have to patch the compiler directives.

It also fixes the following:

- When an floating point value happened to have an exact integer value, the JSON would have a trailing period:

  { "floatingpointvalue": 4. }

  This is now fixed:

  { "floatingpointvalue": 4 }
- Errors in datetime conversions happening around the switch to daylight savings time in leapyears - yes, obscure.
  There was an error in the code section surrounded by `{$IFDEF WINDOWSNT_COMPATIBILITY}`

Note that this is still defined by default, I suggest you disable the define , e.g. with `{.$IFDEF WINDOWSNT_COMPATIBILITY}` [who needs to run on Windows NT nowadays?], which lets the OS handle datetime conversions:

```
{$ELSE}
function TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime(
  lpTimeZoneInformation: PTimeZoneInformation;
  lpLocalTime, lpUniversalTime: PSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

function SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(
  lpTimeZoneInformation: PTimeZoneInformation;
  lpUniversalTime, lpLocalTime: PSystemTime): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
{$ENDIF}
```