# How do I pretty-print JSON in Delphi?

Tags: json, delphi, formatting, pascal, pretty-print

I am looking for a function that will take a string of JSON as input and format it with line breaks and indentations (tabs).

Example:
I have input line:

```js
{"menu": {"header": "JSON viewer", "items": [{"id": "Delphi"},{"id": "Pascal", "label": "Nice tree format"}, null]}}
```

And want to get a readable result as text:

```js
{
   "menu":{
      "header":"JSON viewer",
      "items":[
       {
         "id":"Delphi"
       },
       {
         "id":"Pascal",
         "label":"Nice tree format"
       },
       null
      ]
   }
}
```

I found a lot of examples for PHP and C#, but not for Delphi.
Could someone help with such a function?

**Update - Solution with SuperObject:**

```
function FormatJson (InString: WideString): string; // Input string is "InString"
var
  Json : ISuperObject;
begin
  Json := TSuperObject.ParseString(PWideChar(InString), True);
  Result := Json.AsJson(true, false); //Here comes your result: pretty-print JSON
end;
```

Comment: Nice of you to share the answer.

Comment: If you simply changed your input parameter type to `WideString`, you wouldn't need *any* of that conversion code; the compiler would the equivalent task automatically any time you called `FormatJson`. Just change the type, and you can replace the first seven lines with `Json := TSuperObject.ParseString(PWideChar(InString), True)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the superobject library, make sure that you use [the latest version from the repository file, not the 1.2.4 ZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445280/superobject-cannot-handle-null-string/18462331#18462331).

Then you can format your TSuperObject object with `.AsJSON(true)` (the 'true' does the trick).

[ Note that you have no control over the order in which the JSON fields are displayed ]

[ And to create your object from the string: `var lJSON : ISuperObject; lJSON := SO(string);` ]

Comment: Your advice worked for me, thanks! Just got a small problem with "TSuperObject.ParseString(mystring, true);" where mystring coud not be a string type but PWideString istead.

Answer (score 21):

If you do not want to use any external library, and you're using a delphi XE5 or newer, there is a very handy `TJson.Format()` function in the `REST.Json` unit.

```
uses json, REST.Json;

{ ... }    

function FormatJSON(json: String): String;
var
  tmpJson: TJsonObject;
begin
  tmpJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json);
  Result := TJson.Format(tmpJson);

  FreeAndNil(tmpJson);
end;
```

Comment: Be aware that as of Delphi Berlin Update 2 the TJson.Format function produces human readable, but not Json compatible output as it does not properly escape anything but double quotes.

Comment: In Tokio tmpJson must be TJsonValue: `function FormatJSON(json: String): String;
var
  tmpJson: TJsonValue;
begin
  tmpJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(json);
  Result := TJson.Format(tmpJson);
  FreeAndNil(tmpJson);
end;`

Comment: Since Delphi 10.3 Rio: `REST.Json.TJson.Format` [is deprecated](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/REST.Json.TJson.Format) ("Use `TJSONAncestor.Format` instead"); See [Alex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73093198/1951524) below.

Answer (score 8):

You may also use the [following methods](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/commit/83db96192af1792412dd2d8cef821d4481b83666) of our Open Source `SynCommons.pas` unit:

```
var json,new: RawUTF8;
begin
  json := '{"menu": {"header": "JSON viewer", "items": [{"id": "Delphi"},{"id": "Pascal", "label": "Nice tree format"}, null]}}';
  new := JSONReformat(json,jsonHumanReadable);
  ...
```

Here `new` will contain:

```js
{
  "menu": {
    "header": "JSON viewer",
    "items": 
    [
      {
        "id": "Delphi"
      },
      {
        "id": "Pascal",
        "label": "Nice tree format"
      },
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

If you use the `jsonUnquotedPropName` format:

```
  new := JSONReformat(json,jsonUnquotedPropName);
```

you will get the following extended syntax (similar to the one used in *JavaScript* or *MongoDB* shell):

```js
{
  menu: {
    header: "JSON viewer",
    items: 
    [
      {
        id: "Delphi"
      },
      {
        id: "Pascal",
        label: "Nice tree format"
      },
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

This syntax is accepted as valid input for all the JSON functions of our Open Source framework, as alternative to the default JSON syntax. We found it pretty useful, e.g. for configuration files.

Note that our `JSONReformat()` function is very fast. It converts the huge 190 MB of unconformatable JSON content from [CityLots](https://github.com/zemirco/sf-city-lots-json) into 400 MB of beautified JSON (intended and with line fields) in 1.4 seconds. *SuperObject* is just able to read it in 10 seconds, and uses 1.1 GB just for storing the 190 MB of content. And DBXJSON is not even able to load the data: it consumes all 32 bit memory - under Win64 (XE6), it takes 50 seconds and uses 3 GB of RAM to read the 190 MB of JSON. See [this article for some numbers](http://blog.synopse.info/post/json-benchmark-delphi-mormot-superobject-dwsjson-dbxjson).

Comment: Note: Our `SynCommons.pas` unit works from Delphi 6 up to XE6, in both Win32 and Win64 platforms, and does fully support Unicode, even on the Delphi 7 revision you are still using. In fact, the unit (and this `JSONReformat()` function) does all the process directly in UTF-8, without any memory allocation of the data into `string` or `widestring`. Just use the supplied `StringToUTF8()` or `UTF8ToString()` functions to work with your `string` variables.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit old, but if anyone is interested Delphi's native System.JSON unit can do this too. Sample uses a TMemo and a TButton to format the JSON

```
procedure TForm1.btnFormatJSONClick(Sender: TObject);
const
 DEF_INDENT = 2;
var
 JO : TJSONObject;
begin
 try
  JO := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(memoJSON.Text) as TJSONObject;
  memoJSON.Text := JO.Format(DEF_INDENT);
 except
  on E:Exception do
   begin
    MessageDlg('Error in JSON syntax', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
   end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: FYI Delphi 10.3 or newer is needed for TJSONObject.Format

Comment: Using the `System.JSON` unit for formatting JSON is also better than the old deprecated `REST.Json` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Delphi XE or newer, you can use the [delphi-xe-json](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-xe-json/) library

```
function PrettyPrint (aJSON : string) : string;
var
  jo : IJSONObject
begin
  jo := TJSON.NewObject(aJSON);
  result := jo.ToString(true);
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this advice also! I still use Delphi 7 because my project is too big and too old :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Delphi 10.3 Rio, no `REST.Json` required:

```delphi
function Format_JSON(Value: String; Indentation: Integer = 4): String; inline;
var
  JV: TJSONValue; // not TJSONObject
begin
  JV := nil;
  try
    try
      JV := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Value);
         // TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Value) as TJSONObject cast fails
      Result := JV.Format(Indentation);
    except
      on E: Exception do Log_Exception(E);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(JV);
  end;
end;
```