# Where do I start with JSON?

Tags: json, delphi, parsing

I am complete blank about JSON but I would like to be able to read some data from the URL http://stokercloud.dk/dev/getdriftjson.php?mac=oz8hp and be able to store them im a DB.
But I don't know where to start, so I thought I would ask here for hints and maybe some links to samples that I might learn from 
I know that the output might look confusing, but I have a list of what each item is.

- the file is runtime data from my pelletburner

Comment: We don't do lists of hints, and a request for links to samples and tutorials is clearly stated as being off0-topic in the [help/on-topic]. (They fall under the "tool, library, or favorite off-site resource".) We also don't go somewhere else to see what the content is that you're discussing. There are many posts here about JSON (including many about Delphi and JSON). Please do some research first, and then when you have a **specific** question you can explain the problem here, include the *relevant parts* of your code that are causing you difficulty, and ask that **specific** question.

Comment: Start at [ECMA-404/The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: Then I am very sorry for asking - will newer do that again.

Comment: @SirRufo - Really! I think he needs a two sentence explanation that JSON is a text format for interchange of data and there is a library in virtually any language he cares to use.  Don't send him to a big longer standards library to waste his time.

Comment: @toby websearch yields that information

Answer (score 16):

The [JSON specification](http://json.org) is the first page to read. The standard is so simple it is easy to understand it from this page.

I found [a wider tutorial, with illustrations and more resources](http://www.w3resource.com/JSON/introduction.php). Nice to see.

[image: JSON explained]

Here is the conclusion of this web page:

> - JSON is a open,text based, light-weight data interchange format specified as RFC4627, came to the developer world in 2005 and it's
>     popularity is increased rapidly.
> - JSON uses Object and Array as data structures and strings, number, true, false and null as values. Objects and arrays can be nested
>     recursively.
> - Most (if not all) modern programming languages can be used to work with JSON.
> - NoSQL databases, which are evolved to get rid of the bottlenecks of the Relational Databases, are using JSON to store data.
> - JSON gives developers a power to choose between XML and JSON leading to more flexibility.
> - Besides NoSQL, AJAX, Package Management, and integration of APIs to the web application are the major areas where JSON is being used
>     extensively.

IMHO the main point with JSON is that it contains *documents*, or arrays of documents. There is less data types than with Delphi (e.g. no official date/time, and just one numeric type). It is an *exchange format*, which is widely used now, and, from my own experiment, easier to work with than XML, from both human and computer sides.

In Delphi, you have several libraries around, mainly:

- [SuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/checkout)
- [XSuperObject](https://code.google.com/p/x-superobject/)
- [dwsJSON](https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/source/browse/trunk/Source/dwsJSON.pas)
- [lkJSON](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/)
- [DBXJSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON) which ships with newer versions of Delphi;
- [mORMot for Win32/Win64](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/JSON)
- [SynCrossPlatformJSON](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=10674#p10674)

About performance, [you can take a look at our blog article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/json-benchmark-delphi-mormot-superobject-dwsjson-dbxjson). *DBXJSON* (and the official JSON unit of Delphi) is by far the slowest, and somewhat difficult to work with. Some methods for easy access to the JSON document content are missing. Other libraries are much easier to work with. Our version shipped with *mORMot* is very fast, as is *dwsJSON*. *SuperObject* is slower than those, especially for huge content, and *XSuperObject* is slow (but cross-platform). Our *SynCrossPlatformJSON* unit is also cross-platform, very fast, and has a variant-based document access.

Some code using *mORMot* library:

```
uses
  SynCrtSock,
  SynCommons;

procedure test;
var json: RawUTF8;
    jsondata: TDocVariantData;
    i: integer;
begin
  json := TWinHttp.Get('http://stokercloud.dk/dev/getdriftjson.php?mac=oz8hp');
  jsondata := DocVariantData(_json(json).jsondata)^;
  for i := 0 to jsondata.Count-1 do
    writeln(jsondata.Values[i]); // here all items are converted back to JSON and written
end;
```

Comment: Nice typo "which *whips* with newer versions of Delphi" It works :P

Comment: I have been looking for these mORMot libraries, but I simply can't find where to download.

Comment: https://github.com/synopse/mORMot or http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_113

Answer (score 1):

1. To learn JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), you'd read [JSON on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).
2. To download data from url, you can use `TIdHttp`, which is an Http client of Indy framework.
3. To parse JSON, I'd suggest use [superobject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/). It includes great examples in `demos`  directory.

Comment: the superobject wiki page is simply blank https://code.google.com/p/superobject/w/list

Comment: @Gaetano Thanks for correcting me. Examples are included in download package. `superobject` works very stable in many of my projects.

Comment: **DO NOT** download the 1.2.4 source ZIP file, but go to the source tab to download up-to-date source. See my notes at [SuperObject cannot handle null string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445280/superobject-cannot-handle-null-string)

Comment: I'm still wondering why SuperObject claims to be Linux/FPC compatible in its project page, whereas the current source code currently is not.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez A new iteration of SuperObject called `XSuperObject` introduces multi-platform ability. However, I'm finding all kinds of bugs in it.

Comment: @JerryDodge yes xsuperobject is cross platform but slow. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24232359/458259

Answer (score 0):

JSON is an interchange form for sending data between anything that needs to have data sent to it.  Its simplicity is its strength.

The text is valid javascript and so can be interpreted by any javascript compiler, but is now so popular that virtually every language now has a json parser built in or as a library ( see http://json.org/ scroll down to the bottom).

Basically JSON is a very simple structured text.  If you google JSON Library Delphi you should get some solutions or for any other language you want to use.