# Super Object - spaces in element names

Tags: json, delphi, superobject

I'm using Super Object as a JSON parser. I ran into a problem while working with a third-party API. The API returns JSON with spaces in the element names. However, Super Object does not work with spaces. I observed behavior where it treats the space as the end quote, thus ignoring anything after the space.

```
{ "state abbreviation":"KY", "state":"Kentucky" }
```

I believe the key is that `state` is also the name of another element. When I try to read `state abbreviation` it returns the value of `state` instead.

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This MCVE indicates that SuperObject is working correctly with spaces in the name of the element, I used the latest version of the [source code](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) and Delphi XE7:

```
program SO40958627;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SuperObject,
  System.SysUtils;

var
  obj: ISuperObject;

begin
  try
   obj := SO('{ "state":"Kentucky", "state abbreviation":"KY" }');
   Writeln(obj.AsObject.S['state']);
   Writeln(obj.AsObject.S['state abbreviation']);
   Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Output from program:

```
Kentucky 
KY
```

It seems that you are not using the latest version of the source code, or that the defect is located elsewhere in your program...

Comment: See my comments and answer under [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445280/superobject-cannot-handle-null-string) regarding the availability of SuperObject versions